# String manipulation in C#: split on `/`

Tags: c#, string, file-io

I need to extract headstone data from an inscription file (structured text file). From this file I am supposed to extract the name of a deceased person, date of birth (or age) and also personal messages. The application should be able to analyse a raw text file and then extract information and display it in tabular form.

The raw text files looks like this:

> In loving memory of/JOHN SMITH/who died on 13.02.07/at age 40/we will
>   miss you/In loving memory of/JANE AUSTIN/who died on 10.06.98/born on
>   19.12.80/hope you are well in heaven.

Basically `/` is a delimiter and the name of a deceased person is always in capital letters. I have tried to use `String.Split()` and substring methods but I can't get it to work for me; I can only get raw data without the delimiter (`Environment.Newline`) but I don't know how to extract specific information.

Comment: can you show us the codez that you've tried so far? We may be able to point out where it needs correcting

Comment: How are different records delimited? I tried to fix up the post, but I wasn't clear on this point.

Comment: Indeed is each new record on a new line within the file?

Comment: Michael: Yeah, sounds like the newline is the delimiter, but he used / to distinguish them for us.

Comment: They didn't get very old.  These dates are in the 19th century?

Comment: This sounds like a great homework assignment to learn regex with.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need something like:

- Open your data file (`System.IO`)
- For each line, do (tip: pick a stream where you can read line by line)

  - Split them by "/" getting a `string[]`
  - Arrays in C# starts at 0; so splitted[1] will be that name, ans so on
  - Store that information in a managed collection (maybe to use generics?)
- Display that collection in a tabular view

Answer (score 0):

Check out [How to: Use Regular Expressions to Extract Data Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8t0w9hz.aspx).  I know the example is in C++, but the Regex and Match classes should help you get started

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences) is another good example of parsing out individual sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought something like this would do the trick

```
 private static void GetHeadStoneData()
 {
    using(StreamReader read = new StreamReader("YourFile.txt"))
    {
       const char Delimter = '/';
       string data;
       while((data = read.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
            string[] headStoneInformation = data.Split(Delimter);
            //Do your stuff here, e.g. Console.WriteLine("{0}", headStoneInformation[0]);
       }
    }
 }
```