# Sentence Splitter testing file

Tags: java, python, perl

I am looking for a testing file for my Sentence Splitter Application, and i hope the file can cover as many cases as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: How should your senteces be splitted, and on what conditions?

Comment: The language is English. The algorithm splits text based on Uppercase/Lowercase, Punctuations or language grammar. It is a complex algorithm, so I'd like to test it in as more cases as possible. A very simple example is sentence "Dr. John said his staff I.D. number is not 3.1415." should be in one sentence, but the case at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences should be split into 6 sentences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the documentation for [`Lingua::Sentence`](http://p3rl.org/Lingua::Sentence). It names the corpus it uses, and also related sentence splitting modules. Peruse the test files.