# how to find the number sentences in a string

Tags: vb.net

How to find the number for sentences in a String data ?

Edit: Ok I came up with this after following Wipqozn's method

```
Dim str As String = "This . is .  a . text."
Dim maxCount As Integer = str.Count
Dim intSent As Integer = 1
Dim singleChar As Char

For i = 1 To maxCount
    singleChar = str.Chars(i)          ' Getting an error here
    If singleChar = "." Then
        intSent = intSent + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox("Number of sentence = " & intSent)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you even attempted this, or did you just go to SO to find an answer?

Comment: If it's homework, please tag as homework. What happened to showing the work you have done before you ask for help?

Comment: If I could do it myself I would have never asked it here . And I am trying to do this for the past 1. 20  hours.

Comment: @Kirk:  This sums up pretty much every questions he asks on SO

Comment: @Kirk, Matt That's because I am clueless where to begin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 2: set Dim maxCount As Integer = str.Count-1. by the same notation as mentioned below, since the array starts at 0, it ends at str.Count-1. So the last element you want to check str.Count-1, not str.Count.

Edit: I believe you error at singleChar = str.Chars(i) is because you set i=1. Unless I am mistaken, arrays initialize at '0' in BASIC (which is all a string is). So the first character is really at str.Chars(0) not str.Char(1). Also, when you get an error, you should post the error in your question. Makes it a lot easier for us to understand and help you with your problem =)

[Here.](http://vb.net-informations.com/string/vb.net_String_Chars.htm) That's how you examine each character of a string. You'll need to use a loop to walk through and examine each element of the string, comparing it to some pre-defined value(s)(pre-defined by you) that indicate the start of (or end of) a sentence.

Comment: You should be using `i = 0 to maxCount - 1`

Comment: wouldn't Dim maxCount As Integer = str.Count-1  be faster? Actually the -best- method would probably be to just use str.Count-1, and not bother with maxCount at all.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the String data, using whatever you decide terminates a "sentence" as a splitter (probably multiple characters, such as a period or an exclamation mark), and then count the segments in the returned array.

EDIT:
Learn how to use regular expressions, in VB.net, via the following [link](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/RegExNET_2.htm):

And then use this regular expression:

```
@"(\S.+?[.!?])(?=\s+|$)"
```

As demoed in C#, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences)

Comment: Or just count, right? Doesn't seem necessary to actually create an array if you're not going to use it for anything.

Comment: I mentioned splitter, and, if I remember correctly, doesn't any split method in vb.net return an array automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is counting periods, you could just use

> str.Split(New Char() {"."c}).Length -1