# How to select first two sentences from database?

Tags: php, sentence

Currently i am doing this to get the first 20 words:

```
   $thewhat = $row['about_field'];

   $shortened = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $thewhat), 0, 20));
```

But it looks messy, how can i do it so that only first 2 sentences are selected?

Comment: End of sentence is only .(dot) or !,?,!?,... etc.

Comment: Take a look at this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences

Answer (score 1):

If your sentences are delimited with dots you could try

```
$shortened = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $thewhat), 0, 2)) . '.';
```

Since this will only work for sentences delimited with dots and sentences without dots in the sentence here's a regex that could help you with most parts:

```
$pattern = '/(\S.+?[.!?])(?:\s+|$)/';
$matches = preg_split($pattern, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); 
$shortened = $matches[0] .' '. $matches[1];
```

The regex is stolen from: [What is a regular expression for parsing out individual sentences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences/1936398#1936398) but is slightly altered to not include the matched whitespaces after each sentence.

Comment: what if the users didn't use . and used ? or !

Comment: @AAA as I mentioned in my answer my solution only works if the sentences are delimited with dots, else it quickly gets much trickier.

Comment: ok in any case what happens if dot is not used, will it still shorten or just display everything

Comment: It will match as much it can until it reaches two dots. Which the above code would interpret as two sentences.

Comment: And you will also have the problem with nested sentences, e.g. if there's a quote inside the sentence, the quote itself can end with a dot - but would that mean that the sentence is ended? Also when you use abbreviations it uses dots.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
//extend this regexp [.?] as you need.
$text = 'codepad is an online compiler/interpreter, and a simple collaboration tool.Paste your code below, and codepad will run it and give you a short URL you can use to share it in chat or email? qwe asd zxc.';
$sentences = preg_split('/([.?]+)/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE); 
/*
print_R($sentences); 
Array
(
    [0] => codepad is an online compiler/interpreter, and a simple collaboration tool
    [1] => .
    [2] => Paste your code below, and codepad will run it and give you a short URL you can use to share it in chat or email
    [3] => ?
    [4] =>  qwe asd zxc
    [5] => .
)
*/
$shorted = $sentences[0] . $sentences[1] . $sentences[2] . $sentences[3];
echo $shorted;
?>
```