# Why this regular expression dead halfway?

Tags: c#, regex

I have one html document(size>3mb) contains 1k+ empty char 0 in its body.

I have a text processing program which will load the html , using regular expression to filter out all the tags,eg:

```
 input = Regex.Replace(input, "<([^^]*?)>", " ", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

and using the following one to retrieve sentences:

```
     Regex rx = new Regex(@"(\S.+?[.!?])(?=\s+|$)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(input))
            {
               //do somthing
            }
```

So far, the tag filtering works fine, but the above one fails halfway unless I remove all char 0 in advance.

```
 input =input.Replace(string.Format("{0}",(char)(0)),"");
```

"Fail" meaning that the worker thread is frozen at line:  `foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(input))`

Do anyone know why only the above regular expression fails and why no exception is thrown?

[For Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences)

Comment: `<([^^]*?)>` looks like a happy man with an ear piercing

Comment: The Beauty of Programming   :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple points:

1. Regular expressions are not a good tool for processing HTML files.  Often the rules of HTML are too complex for a regex solution.  [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) would be a better solution to strip HTML tags and just get the text.
2. There's such a thing as [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) which can appear to freeze your regular expression.  I recently [created a video](http://regexhero.net/videos/12/optimizing-for-performance) demonstrating some common mistakes to look out for in this regard.

Now on to your specific problem.  To prevent a lot of backtracking from occurring you might try the nonbacktracking subexpression `(?>pattern)`.

```
(?>\S.+?[.!?])(?=\s+|$)
```

This is good to use whenever the backtracking inside the subexpression (or group) isn't really necessary to achieve your end result.  In some cases it'll drastically improve performance.

In addition to that, I'd suggest removing the `IgnoreCase` option since that's just slowing things down and isn't necessary for what you're doing.  And then use the `Compiled` option as Yorye mentioned.  Also, at times (depending on the nature of your regular expression) you can really benefit from using the `RightToLeft` option and I think that'll be the case here.  In my test `RightToLeft` was 60 times faster.

All that said, you might try this...

```
var MyRegex = new Regex(@"(?>\S.+?[.!?])(?=\s+|$)", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

It can be helpful to initialize your Regex just once as above and then you can reuse `MyRegex` multiple times.  This is especially true when you consider the additional overhead that comes from the `Compiled` option.

---

**Update**

I did a little more testing on this and found that the `RightToLeft` option was actually breaking things.  Also, your regular expression is usually pretty fast if you're just dealing with a bunch of sentences.  It's slow when the sentences are really long (or if they never end).

So you might set a maximum sentence length to force the regular expression to give up sooner...

```
\S.{2,250}[.!?](?=\s|$)
```

Another thing that might help is adding `\n` (line feed) to the punctuation list...

```
\S.{2,250}[.!?\n](?=\s|$)
```

**Update #2**

I found another approach which is even faster.  Rather than matching sentences, it's much more efficient to [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx) on punctuation.  That's especially true in the cases I listed above (very long sentences).

You can split with this...

```
(?<=[.!?])\s+
```

Then what you end up with is an array of sentences.

Comment: To prevent catastrophic backtracking, you just need to follow a few simple rules: Don't place two overlapping set constructs next to each other (in your case \S and .+ and [.!?]) and try not to use reluctant constructs such as +?, they're almost always needed if you have overlap anyway. `\S[^.!?]+[!.?](?=\s|$)` is probably a lot faster and will cause fewer false positives. Though it might fail on sentences that use !!! or ... or ?!?!?! which `\S[^.!?]+[!.?]+(?=\s|$)` would catch.

Comment: As for the Html Agility Pach, you can use `<HtmlDocument>.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")` to grab all text from a HTML file in one go. Just stick all of those `(Node.InnerText)` in a stringbuilder and you're all set.

Comment: @jessehouwing - Good points.  Although, in my test your regular expressions return 12 matches whereas the original (and mine) returns 19.

Comment: @jessehouwing - I haven't tested things too much, but it may in fact be that your regular expression is more correct for finding sentences.  But I was just pointing out that the results are different.

Comment: That is to be expected, as .+? can cross over any [.?!] in order to fulfill the match, and will do so eventually, and my expression cannot. Thus matching more lines. It's also why my expression should be much faster. Whether or not that's correct is up to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You should add '\' before special regex characters (such as . or ? or), in case you want the actual characters (otherwise - I don't understand your second regex).

Secondly, It might not be actually stuck, just taking a long time since the file is huge. Try replacing your foreach loop with:

```
var match = rx.Match(input);

while (match.Success)
{
    // do something

    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

And also, add the **RegexOptions.Compiled** flag when initializing the regex and it will make it faster in general (only good if the regex is likely to run more than a few times. Since it causes the initialization to be a tiny bit longer, you might want to consider moving the regex to class scope as a static readonly field).

Comment: My regular expression is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences