# scan(/\p{graph}+/) and Date

Tags: ruby, regex

When I use `scan(/\p{graph}+/)` it works:

```
"ich gehe nach Köln am 12.09.2012".scan(/\p{graph}+/)
=> ["ich", "gehe", "nach", "Köln", "am", "12.09.2012"]
```

But if there is a typing error like "`Köln.am`", then the output is wrong:

```
"ich gehe nach Köln.am 12.09.2012".scan(/\p{graph}+/)
=> ["ich", "gehe", "nach", "Köln.am", "12.09.2012"]
```

When I use `scan(/\p{alnum}+/)`, the Date is not correct:

```
"ich gehe nach Köln.am 12.09.2012".scan(/\p{alnum}+/)
=> ["ich", "gehe", "nach", "Köln", "am", "12", "09", "2012"]
```

Does anyone know another solution?

Comment: You are trying to use Regular Expressions to parse natural language, which basically can't be done. Any solution offered will be incomplete and buggy because Regex is not able to maintain a sense of context.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences

Comment: Each word should stand alone, and the date should be displayed properly: "ich", "gehe", "nach", "Köln", "am", "12.09.2012"

Comment: The problem is that you "know" what you mean by a "word" but regex doesn't, and the definition you have is a very human one which regex cannot replicate. If you need to retrieve very specific information from your user, I'd recommend a different approach than trying to parse free-entry text - I've tried and, believe me, it's really not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this simple case you can check using alternations and match either a series of letters or a series of digits with dots.

```
"ich gehe nach Koeln.am 12.09.2012".scan(/\p{alpha}+|[\d+.]+/)
```

outputs:

```
["ich", "gehe", "nach", "Koeln", ".", "am", "12.09.2012"]
```

or, if you don't want to match the single dot

```
"ich gehe nach Koeln.am 12.09.2012".scan(/\p{alpha}+|\d+(?:\.\d+)*/)
```

output:

```
["ich", "gehe", "nach", "Koeln", "am", "12.09.2012"]
```

Comment: Thank you!!! scan(/\p{alpha}+|\d+(?:\.\d+)*/) is what I need! And for 12-09-2012 and 12/09/2012?

Comment: scan(/\p{alpha}+|\d+(?:[\.\-\/]\d+)*/)

Comment: So, does this work for "ich gehe nach Emilia-Romagna. am 12.09.2012"? ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what result you want, so my answer might be incorrect.

```
"ich gehe nach Köln am 12.09.2012".split /\s/
 => ["ich", "gehe", "nach", "Köln", "am", "12.09.2012"]
```

edit:

Note, that several whitespaces in a row will break the result.

```
"ich gehe nach Köln        am 12.09.2012".split /\s/
 => ["ich", "gehe", "nach", "Köln", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "am", "12.09.2012"]
```

Comment: How does this answer "But if there a typing error like 'Köln.am', then the output is wrong"?

Comment: Each word should stand alone, and the date should be displayed properly: "ich", "gehe", "nach", "Köln", "am", "12.09.2012"