# What is a regular expression for parsing out persian individual sentences?

Tags: c#, regex, nlp, text-processing

I am looking for a good .NET regular expression that I can use for parsing out individual sentences from a Persian body of text.
So I thought of using a pattern to do splitting like if a `.` `؟` `!`  `؛` follows a space and than do the split.
in Persian language there is no Capital letter and the question mark is `؟` and its a right to left language. 
look at this example it has 4 sentences:

> راهی که برایت هموار نیست و تو از میان تمام دغدغه‌های ریز و درشت این شهر انتخاب می‌کنی که یک روزت را با مردگان همراه شوی. بروی به دقیقه 91؛ به‌جایی که با تمام شنیده‌هایت فرق دارد. بروی به مرز بین دنیا و آخرت، به‌جایی که عروجیان راتطهیر می‌کنند، آرایش می‌کنند برای وصال یار؛

i found this question useful [What is a regular expression for parsing out individual sentences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936388/what-is-a-regular-expression-for-parsing-out-individual-sentences) and here is a regular expression for English

```
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"(\S.+?[.!?])(?=\s+|$)");
foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(str)) {
    int i = match.Index;
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oF4uG1/2)

```
([^!؟.؛]+[؟.؛!])
```

which matches everything that doesn't include those characters, then a punctuation?

Comment: thanks but it removes  .؟!؛  from results too. i want to keep them in result sentences

Comment: i think its incorrect regular expression here is exception  :  `Additional information: parsing "([^!؟.؛!]?+[؟.؛])" - Nested quantifier +`